# user growth by create time in elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

I am storing users with `created` field (indexed as date) and I want to retrieve their count related to some date and aggregate it by day for last month. Imagine that every second day there is new signup on the website - so I want to get something like this:

```
date         count
2017-02-01   10
2017-02-02   10
2017-02-03   11
2017-02-04   11
2017-02-05   12
2017-02-06   12
2017-02-07   13
2017-02-08   13
2017-02-09   14
2017-02-10   14
2017-02-11   15
...
```

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Date Histogram Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html), for example:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "registrations_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "created",
                "interval" : "day"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`date_histogram` is helpful but only returns "new users" per day. To get total number of users for specific dates I had to add something like this:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "users": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "created",
                "interval": "day",
                "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "users_stats": {
                    "stats": {
                        "field": "id"
                    }
                },
                "cumulative_users": {
                    "cumulative_sum": {
                        "buckets_path": "users_stats.count"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```